# Create a list of checkboxes in Python 3.4

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python 3.4 and tkinter

I want to create a list of checkboxes. 
However when, just to check, I made a list and displayed it

```
checkbox = [Checkbutton(mainwindow, text = "x")]
checkbox(0).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

It gave me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Users/iamhssingh/Documents/Python/GUICreator/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    checkbox(0).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: it should be checkbox[0].grid(row = 0, column = 0)

Comment: Or checkbox = Checkbutton(mainwindow, text = "x")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an element of a list, use square brackets rather than parentheses:

```
checkbox[0].grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```